# VS2015CE breaks on handled exception, disregarding exception settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, signalr.client, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio 2015 CE (I have a pre-"Xamarin is free now" business license), which uses the SignalR.Client library, and I'm having a hard time debugging my application. This is due to (what I very strongly suspect is) the SignalR.Client library throwing two kinds of exceptions in response to the SignalR server not running:

*System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)*
*System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused*

However, when VS breaks on this code I don't see where this occurred, nor do I get any (dis)assembly. I have turned off all exceptions in **Exception Settings**, but it still happens.

I have put all SignalR code that could throw the exceptions in try/catch blocks, catching both the specific exceptions and general Exception's; VS still breaks on these exceptions, throwing up a message box about the exception and not providing any further info.

The app crashes in release mode as well, on startup, unless the SignalR server is running.

My app doesn't use any web-related libraries or functions outside the SignalR.Client library (version 2.1.2, as 2.2.0 is incompatible with Xamarin.Forms).

My Exception Settings window has the "Add Exception" (plus sign) button grayed out in both normal and debug mode. None of the exceptions are checked. Just My Code is on, but the same thing happens with Just My Code off. I have tried reloading my project, my solution, Visual Studio and my OS. I have tried rebuilding my solution. "Break when this exception type is thrown" is unchecked in the exception dialog box, and it is grayed out.

This is my third month using C# and VS and I'm at a total loss. I feel very out of my depth in debugging this issue, so here I am. If there's any more relevant information I can provide I'll gladly do so.

Thank you for your time.